# Emacs lisp: get RGB components of face?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've recently made a switch to Emacs trunk and the `region` face
color was changed.
And I can't change it back without knowing what it was before.

So I've launched emacs24.3 and see that it was "gtk_selection_bg_color".
This color name isn't valid any more in the trunk.
I've found the color to be "f9b593" with screenshot->gimp->eyedrop method,
but I'd like to know how to do this in Elisp, e.g. something like

```
(get-face-background-rgb 'region)
;; "f9b593"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `color-value`:

> color-values is a compiled Lisp function in `faces.el'. (color-values
>   COLOR &optional FRAME)
>
> Return a description of the color named COLOR on frame FRAME. The
>   value is a list of integer RGB values--(RED GREEN BLUE). These values
>   appear to range from 0 to 65280 or 65535, depending on the system;
>   white is (65280 65280 65280) or (65535 65535 65535). If FRAME is
>   omitted or nil, use the selected frame. If FRAME cannot display COLOR,
>   the value is nil. If COLOR is the symbol `unspecified' or one of the
>   strings "unspecified-fg" or "unspecified-bg", the value is nil.

To get the color of a face, you can use `face-foreground` and `face-background`. In your case, you can use:

```
 (color-values (face-background 'region))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use library [`eyedropper.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/eyedropper.el) or library [`palette.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/palette.el) --- see [Color Palette](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette) --- to get the color of a face at point. And you can use library `palette` to explore colors, to come up with a similar but slightly different color etc.  You can use library [`hexrgb.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hexrgb.el) to examine and modify RGB components of colors.